# Grep -w is ignoring hyphen[-]

Tags: grep

I have text file `sample.txt` like following

```
ID=Sam-S-PA.path1;Name=Sam-S-PA   23   Hz42
ID=GlcAT-S-PA.path1;Name=GlcAT-S-PA 45   iu7s
ID=TfIIA-S-PA.path1;Name=TfIIA-S-PA 76   5ghz
ID=S-PA.path1;Name=S-PA 69 ivcs       
ID=TyrRS-PA.path1;Name=TyrRS-PA 51 Pqas
ID=HisRS-PA.path1;Name=HisRS-PA 32 Majs
```

I would like to extract row containing only S-PA using grep. I tried following command:

```
grep -w "S-PA" sample.txt
```

But it gave a output that included all the entries which I dont want. I want the following output

```
 ID=S-PA.path1;Name=S-PA 69 ivcs
```

Kindly guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't my solution work for you? Please check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using negative look-ahead and look-behind.

```
$ grep -P '(?<![\w-])S-PA(?![\w-])' sample.txt
ID=S-PA.path1;Name=S-PA 69 ivcs
```

Effectively you include `-` into the "word" for word boundary considerations.

`(?<![\w-])` ensures that `S-PA` is not preceded with a word character or `-`. 
Similarly `(?![\w-])` ensures the same for the following characters.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex.

`grep -oE "S-PA (.+)" sample.txt`

or

`egrep -o "S-PA (.+)" sample.txt`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to match `=S-PA` followed with a space. Use

```
grep '=S-PA ' sample.txt
```

or

```
grep '=S-PA[[:blank:]]' sample.txt
```

where `[[:blank:]]` matches either a regular space or a tab char.

See [this regex demo showing how this regex works](https://regex101.com/r/UdWqZb/1).